# Trying to move a mail message to folder, but it doesn't move

Tags: email, folders

I'm trying to move many mail messages to subfolders and they won't move. They moved before—what's going wrong?

Comment: Are you using Mail.app? OS X or iOS? What version of OS?

Comment: In Apple mail open the Window tab in menu bar then select the Activity and observe, it should be showing you how it is moving messages from to (using the IMAP), since your mails are originally stored on your email providers server.

Comment: This is suddenly happening to me to. Using Catalina 10.15.4
Have been using Mail app without issues for years. To my knowledge, nothing significant changed on my Mac since yesterday, when it was working. Using the Activity Viewer, it says it's moving the message -- which disappears for microseconds and then returns to my inbox. Thoughts? Thanks